# Build a web app basing on a dms kernel

Tags: sharepoint, alfresco, dms

I need your help for my question.
I need to build a web based application that should perform some activity of document management. I'm evaluating existing document management solution and I need a solution that expose api via rest or other protocol, so that I can interact with them from my application. 
I read about alfresco, sharepoint and knowledge tree but I find difficult to understant prices for commercial use. Can someone help me with a comparison of function/prices for a commercial use?

Comment: Do you want a support agreement with the system, or are you happy with free but no support?

Comment: I need also support..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Alfresco is available in two versions, [Alfresco Community Edition](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Main_Page) and [Alfresco Enterprise](http://www.alfresco.com/products/one). Alfresco Community is under the [LGPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html). Assuming you want to use it in-house (not distribute it to others), you can use + customise + extend Alfresco Community to your heart's content, without restriction or charge. (LGPL/GPL/etc are distribution licenses, not use licenses, so only kick in when you redistribute). However, Alfresco Community comes with no commercial support, only support provided by the community. For a lot of uses that's good enough, but for other cases you'll want to be able to ring someone for support / get hotfixes backported to your version / etc. In that case...

Alfresco Enterprise is paid for, coming with commercial support (including SLAs, pick up the phone and talk to an expert etc), along with a handful of features that matter in big deployments (clustering being one). Pricing depends on a few things, mostly around size of deployment and SLA, but for small deployments isn't too bad. For big deployments, it can be a huge saving over other systems! Give sales a call, they're very friendly, and only rarely buy me beer ;-)

If you don't want to run your own repo, there's also the [Alfresco Cloud](http://www.alfresco.com/products/cloud) version, which comes with a [public API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_API). With this, Alfresco themselves run and maintain the instance for you, and you can use the public API to store / retrieve / manage / etc your content. It's much simpler to get going with! But you don't quite get as much control or customisation as with the on-premise versions.

SharePoint might already be covered by your existing Microsoft licensing deal, if you have one. If not, you'd need to decide between licensing on a per-server or per-user basis. See [Microsoft pages like this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview-collaboration-software-FX103789438.aspx) to get an idea of the options, then ring your Microsoft sales rep to get an idea of the pricing. In many cases, you'd need to pay someone else for support, so you'd be back to a similar thing as with Alfresco Community vs Enterprise.

If you're not sure what system to go with, you might be safest and best off implementing your project using [CMIS](http://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/cmis/trunk/cmis-v1.1/) (Content Management Interoperability Services). This provides a common way to talk to content repositories, allowing you to store/retrieve/browse/search/permissions/etc irrespective of what the underlying repo is. [Alfresco provide some information](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) on it, and [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) provides open source client libraries for most common programming languages, which makes getting started very quick. There's also an [excellent book on CMIS](http://www.manning.com/mueller/) which I can very much recommend! And not only because the authors of that have been known to buy me beer too... ;-)